# I'm trying to take a close up of a camcorder LCD

Tags: macro

I'm trying to a picture of an image I have paused on a Sony camcorder. The LCD is 6.2cm and has a pixel of 560x220. I'm using a Canon PowerShot SX40HS. I have the Canon on a tripod, micro setting, and have tried ISO 200,400,800,different light settings and still the image shows a lot of grainy little dots.(I guess the pixels of the camcorder image). I cannot get this camcorder disc to load on my computer and I really want this frame to come out clean. Can you help?

Comment: Can you hook the camcorder up to a TV and take a shot of the image on that? Might be much easier.

Comment: ok did that and pixel bumps are gone, but image off tv screen is sort of glassy looking(no duh) and has lines running through it?

Comment: Just to be clear, is the purpose to get a still from the video, or is the purpose to get an image specifically of that video/interface being shown on a screen? (i.e. could you just load the video from the camcorder onto your computer and use VLC to take a screenshot?)

Comment: I don't think loading it on a computer is an option: "I cannot get this camcorder disc to load on my computer" I am interested though in what model the camcorder is. Maybe there is another way to get the video out? Can it display on a computer monitor? That will have high resolution, yet also be small enough to easily control the lighting.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned by @ElendilTheTall, using a TV screen will provide a much better quality image than the small camcorder screen. The TV will have it's own problems though.

You need to have a long enough exposure to allow for the screen's refresh rate and any interlaced content to be displayed, otherwise you may get odd patterns on the screen (lines, darker sections, completely black or white screen).

A good starting point would be to use a 1/30 sec or longer shutter speed. That should be long enough regardless of the screen type to give you a clear image.

Comment: Be aware that Plasma TV screens have other refresh signals 'happening' and what works for a standard scanned screen may not work for plasma

Comment: Also turning off any other light sources in the room will reduce reflections off the screen, giving a higher contrast / clearer image.

Comment: In a room with large windows, the screen may be tented with a dark cloth.